# Multiply by a const some props coordinate with string format

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I want to mulitiply the coordinates of some points with coefficient `coeff`. The problem is that theses coordinates points are in a string props, and it doesn't seem to work if I just multiply them by a {coeff} const. I'm sure this is a trivial problem but I'm kind of a beginner.

Here's the original code (40,5 is the first x1,y1, 70,80 is x2,y2 etc):

```
<Svg height="100" width="100">
  <Polygon
    points="40,5 70,80 25,95"
    fill="lime"
    stroke="purple"
    strokeWidth="1"
  />
</Svg>
```

and here's what I'm try to do :

```
const coeff = 1;
...
<Svg height="100" width="100">
  <Polygon
    points="40*${coeff},5*${coeff} 70*${coeff},80*${coeff} 25*${coeff},95*${coeff}"
    fill="lime"
    stroke="purple"
    strokeWidth="1"
  />
</Svg>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
let coeff = 2;
console.log(`${40*coeff} , ${5*coeff},
${70*coeff}, ${80*coeff} ,${25*coeff},
${95*coeff}`);
```

Here is a simple JS example but can be used similarly in JSX.

Comment: great, that solve my problem! I then just replace the double quotes with brackets for my points property ant it works